# OSX fullscreen mode unexpected behaviour

Tags: macos, opera

I'm facing a very frustrating issue with OSX 10.11.3.

I start recently to work with all my apps using fullscreen mode, and switching between them with CMD+tab. However, sometimes, it does not switch/slide to the app screen. It goes to the empty desktop.

I'm not able to figure out any pattern for this behaviour, it's happening ~10% of the time when I CMD+tab. The only thing i may have noticed is that it tends to be more frequent with some app: Slack, Tower, ...

There is another similar issue I have with Opera. It is set as my default browser but when I click a link in another app, the browser opens it  correctly but my screen goes to the empty desktop and I have to manually switch to Opera...

I'm aware I'm not providing a lot of details here, but I don't have any. This issue is killing my productivity and sanity for weeks now, feel free to ask any questions.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by empty desktop? Everything disappears and you see the empty desktop (like pressing F11)?

Comment: When you open an app fullscreen, OSX keep an empty desktop/screen/space, not sure what is the word for it. I forgot a point, when the CMD+tab mislead me to this desktop, the status bar is the one of the app. So i have to CMD+tab 2 times to show to app again

Comment: @kenorb I think he means the virtual desktops